# Missing update button in Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android-studio

Every time new update came out, I had an option to update my Android Studio.
Now there is only option to download it, and when I click on it, it redirects me to web page like it is my first install. Is there any way to get that button back, or do I have to uninstall and install new version?